# docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "volume": invalid mount path: 'C:/Program Files/Git/etc/todos' mount path must be

Tags: docker, mounted-volumes

I am New to Docker and I am doing their Getting Started tutorial. I have been running through this error while trying to start my container with a mounted volume:

```bash
docker run -dp 3000:3000 --mount type=volume,src=todo-db,target=/etc/todos getting-started
```

I do not understand the error

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is you are mixing volume and mount syntax/options.

You should try this:

docker run -dp 3000:3000 --mount type=bind,src=todo-db,dst=/etc/todos getting-started

In the above, changing type to bind (instead of volume) and changing target to dst.

Answer (score -3):

To address the issue, it is recommended to adjust the command as follows:

```
docker run -dp 3000:3000 --mount type=volume,src=todo-db,target=//etc//todos getting-started
```